# code blocks :: It seems that this project has not been built yet

Tags: codeblocks

im using mac 10.12 and 
i downloaded the code blocks and the command line developer tools 
but when i tried to run any program a window appears and say "It seems like project has not been built yet. Do you wan to build it now?"

and this the build log

```
-------------- Build: Debug in aaaa (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

gcc -Wall -g  -c /Users/macbookproretina13inch/Documents/Programming/aaaa/main.c -o obj/Debug/main.o
Agreeing to the Xcode/iOS license requires admin privileges, please re-run as root via sudo.
Process terminated with status 69 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
0 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))


-------------- Run: Debug in aaaa (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

Checking for existence: /Users/macbookproretina13inch/Documents/Programming/aaaa/bin/Debug/aaaa
Executing: osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal"' -e 'activate' -e 'do script "/Applications/CodeBlocks.app/Contents/MacOS/cb_console_runner DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:. /Users/macbookproretina13inch/Documents/Programming/aaaa/bin/Debug/aaaa "' -e 'end tell'  (in /Users/macbookproretina13inch/Documents/Programming/aaaa/.)
Process terminated with status 0 (0 minute(s), 3 second(s))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download Xcode from the App Store, and run this in the terminal to install Xcode's command-line tools:

> $ xcode-select --install

This will install the essential compilers and tools,and should fix the problem.

Comment: thanks but is this well work for mac cause it seem like for windows ?